# Java Pos FiscalPrinter

Tags: java, javapos, fiscal

How correctly print receipts in Java POS?
I try to make module in java, that will work with fiscal registrar PIRIT K.

I get some troubles:

Sell.

```
FiscalPrinter printer = new FiscalPrinter();
printer.open("PIRIT");
printer.claim(1);
printer.beginFiscalReceipt(true);
printer.printRecItem(premadeString("Test"), 2, 1 * 1000, 2, 1, premadeString("Test"));
printer.printRecTotal(2, 100, "0");
printer.printRecVoid("Close check");
```

It's wont print VAT values after total. But Vat table in registrar is ok.

Refund:

```
FiscalPrinter printer = new FiscalPrinter();
printer.open("PIRIT");
printer.claim(1);
printer.setFiscalReceiptType(FPTR_RT_REFUND); 
printer.beginFiscalReceipt(true);
printer.printRecRefund("Тестовый возврат", 1, 2);
printer.printRecVoid("Close Check");
```

It's simple give me exception "error value of station". In what state printer should be for refund? And yes, printRecIntemRefund not supported by driver.

I use printRecVoid(); for see output and not keep my operation in fiscal memory.

How can i fix it? Somebody already faced with similar problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was driver developers issue.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: @Robert When i posted this question, i don't understand the main work principles of JAVA-POS and think, that i do something wrong. but later i decompiled driver, and saw that there is some mistakes in driver itself, so update question. or i should delete it in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Try the method:

```
setEnabled(true);
```

before or after claim

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's recommended to take [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)